# Javascript in Asp.net,C#

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I'm using javascript in asp.net.
I want to use javascript's datas in codebehind.
How can I make this?

```
function init()
{
...
...
trigger: function (e) {
    var lonlat = map.getLonLatFromPixel(e.xy);

    N = lonlat.lat;
    E = lonlat.lon;

    alert("You are near hear: " + N + " N, " + E + " E");
}
```

How can I sending N and E variable to code behind.(so useable code behind)

Comment: It would help if your Javascript snippet made any sense.

Comment: Good time to learn AJAX?

Comment: No. I dont known ajax. But I can learn

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

Here `Hiddenfield1 and Hiddenfield2` are two html hidden field

JS

```
document.getElementById("Hiddenfield1").value=N;
document.getElementById("Hiddenfield2").value=E;
```

in C#

```
Response.Write(Hiddenfield1.Value);
Response.Write(Hiddenfield2.Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function init()
{ bla bla bla
trigger: function (e) {
var lonlat = map.getLonLatFromPixel(e.xy);

N = lonlat.lat;
E = lonlat.lon;

document.getElementById("Hidden1").value=N;
document.getElementById("Hidden2").value=E;

alert("You are near hear: " + N + " N, " + E + " E");
}


</script>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <input id="Hidden1" type="hidden" runat="server" />
        <input id="Hidden2" type="hidden" runat="server" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClientClick="init()"  Text="Button"
            onclick="Button1_Click" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

In code behind:-

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write(Hidden1.Value);
        Response.Write(Hidden2.Value);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to add two controls to the page.

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="lat" />
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="lon" />
```

In the trigger function set the value of the field:

```
document.getElementById('lat').value = lonlat.lat;
document.getElementById('lon').value = lonlat.lon;
```

In the server side code take the `Text` property of the controls.